# iOS App Update - Restricting new version to single platform

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

My application is currently present in Appstore for both iPad and iPhone platforms. Now, i want to update the appstore app but restricted to only iPhone platform (will later release the iPad version).

1) During Appstore submission, Xcode throws validation error that "this version doesn't compatible with previous version (not supporting iPad version)". Should i need to support iPad version also?

2) Ignoring that error, i tried proceeding with the appstore distribution. Its never get uploaded. waited for around more than 2 hrs. It showed "Your application is being uploaded"

[image]

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, once you've submitted an app that supports both platforms, from that point on each update also needs to support both platforms (as you've found).

The only way around this is to create a new app with a different bundle id.

In your case, as you will support both eventually you may have to delay release until the iPad version is complete.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Ashley. If i upload with different bundle id, My app will get installed as a newer app instead overwriting the existing one?

Comment: Correct. Only apps that keep the same bundle id will be "overwritten" (i.e. upgraded). If you use a new bundle id it will be installed as a new app.

Comment: But, what about those first two errors? Do you have any idea?

Comment: They're all related - fix the devices error and the other will clear too.

Comment: Thanks Ashley. Will see.